# Adding Angular plugin to controller

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs

I have a .net project with angular. I am trying to add angular-hotkeys (https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys/) to the project and use it.

I added it to the project with nuget and added it to my bundle.
[image]

Then I add the hotkeys to the controller where it takes dependencies and try to add the function.

```
angular.module('mainApp')
    .controller('ndcController', ["$scope", "$location", "$timeout", "fieldService", "entityService", "$filter", "authorizedUserService", "$q", "gerimedService", function ($scope, $location, $timeout, fieldService, entityService, $filter, authorizedUserService, $q, gerimedService,hotkeys) {
        hotkeys.add({
            combo: 'ctrl+up',
            description: 'This one goes to 11',
            callback: function () {
                var test = "";
            }
        });
    }]);
```

The page just hangs loading and the Ajax never finishes coming in. If I remove the function (hotkeys.add()) the page loads even with the added hotkeys dependency.

I also added the dependencies to the BundleConfig.cs:

```
 public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.2.js",
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js",
                        "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                        "~/Scripts/angular.js",
                        "~/Scripts/angular-route.js",
                        "~/Scripts/angular-animate.js",
                        "~/Scripts/knockout-3.1.js",
                        "~/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js",
                        "~/JavaScript/validateNumberInput.js",
                        "~/JavaScript/Accounting.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js",
                        //"~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                        "~/Scripts/moment.js",
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                        "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
                        "~/Scripts/hotkeys.js",
                        "~/Scripts/mask.js"//below is my code
                                           //"~/JavaScript/Module/Module.js",
                                           //"~/JavaScript/Filters/Filters.js",
                                           //"~/JavaScript/Services/Services.js",
                                           //"~/JavaScript/Directives/Directives.js",
                                           //"~/JavaScript/Controllers/HomeControllers.js"
                        ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
            //            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
            //,"~/Content/site.css"
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/bootstrap.css", "~/Content/site.css", "~/Content/hotkeys.css"
                ));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));

            //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/app").Include("~/JavaScript/ApprovalsDisplay.js"));
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Edit: Console error:

```
"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: hotkeysProvider <- hotkeys
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/unpr?p0=cfp.hotkeysProvider%20%3C-%20cfp.hotkeys
minErr/<@http://localhost:51059/Scripts/angular.js:78:12.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in your controller. there is a hotkey dependency missing

```
angular.module('mainApp', ['ui.mask', "ngRoute", "cfp.hotkeys"])
    .controller('ndcController', ["$scope", "$location", "$timeout", "fieldService", "entityService", "$filter", "authorizedUserService", "$q", "gerimedService","hotkeys", function ($scope, $location, $timeout, fieldService, entityService, $filter, authorizedUserService, $q, gerimedService,hotkeys) {
        hotkeys.add({
            combo: 'ctrl+up',
            description: 'This one goes to 11',
            callback: function () {
                var test = "";
            }
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and without the hotkeys.add() function there it still hangs.

Comment: Yes, let me add it to question.

Comment: the problem is you need to add this dependency to controller "cfp.hotkeys" not "hotkeys" I have updated my answer

Comment: It makes sense what you say. I looked at the file and cfp.hotkeys is what it shopuld be called. However, I still get the same problem it changes to: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: cfp.hotkeysProvider <- cfp.hotkeys`

Comment: Do you have index.html file? if you have it can you include a script tag for loading this angular-hotkeys js file

Comment: I got it. I had to add it to the module file     angular.module('mainApp', ['ui.mask', "ngRoute", "cfp.hotkeys"]) as well as your 1st solution. You can add that if you want and ill choose you as answer. Thanks!